# Submit Order on Drupal 7 Custom Theme Redirects Back to Checkout Page

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

When I submit an order on my custom theme using ubercart on Drupal 7, I get redirected to the cart/checkout page again. The order shows up as being abandoned. The redirected is the checkout page again and has everything from the previous order but the full credit card information(last 4 digits and cvv). I am not getting an error messages that I am aware of after checking log files.

I tried adding the mytheme_uc_checkout_pane_cart_review function to my theme's template.php file as described [on the documentation here](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/32119/how_theme_checkout_pane_ubercart_3) to see if that helped, but that didn't seem to work. How could I fix this issue so the order goes through and gets to the completed order page.

In addition, I found another person having the same issue, but mind is not caused by a non-valid product. [Link to that issue Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1882624)

Based on some looking The checkout works fine on the default theme Bartik 7.50. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I  just have a similar problem with a very simple solution. Look in Reports > Recent log messages, if your page can find the js files: jquery-ui, jquery-x.x.x.min.js.
if not, you need to fix it.
In my case, I forget to put this in my [customtheme]/templates/html.tpl.php, that I have modified previously:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme() .'/' ?>js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme() .'/' ?>js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```